# I want to extract data from a website and then I went it to display on my webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping

### First, I have to extract it and save it on the CSV file. This is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

result = requests.get("https://www.health.govt.nz/our-work/diseases-and-conditions/covid-19-novel-coronavirus/covid-19-current-situation/covid-19-current-cases")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src,'lxml')

cov19_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "table-style-two"})
cov19_table_data = cov19_table.find_all("tbody")

headings = []
# gives me headings 
for th in cov19_table_data[0].find_all("th"): #3rows
    headings.append(th.text.replace('\n',' ').strip())
#print(headings)

t_data = []
for td in cov19_table_data[0].find_all("td"):
    t_data.append(td.text.strip())
print(t_data)

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline="") as new_file:
  csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)
  csv_writer.writerows(t_data)
```

---

Whenever I open the data.csv file i get this data

### [image: This is how it saving]

The original table looks like this:
[image: This is what I want to extract]

Comment: How about simply providing a link to the page so its clear where the data comes from?

Comment: https://www.health.govt.nz/our-work/diseases-and-conditions/covid-19-novel-coronavirus/covid-19-current-situation/covid-19-current-cases

Comment: Just to make things a bit clearer: you show the code, you show what you get, you show the original table format... but at the end, what's your question? what do you wish as the desired output format and what's the problem you are facing?  [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Your `t_data` is just a list of columns - you have only one row - read about [writerows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) - it needs a list of rows , each row is a list of columns.

Use

```
with open('data.csv', 'w', newline="") as new_file:
  csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)
  csv_writer.writerows( [t_data] )  # fix here
```

It's probably still better to not scape data and add it to your page without attribution to the source. Adding a link to it would give people ways to read more about it.

You might also want to use the headings and some other seperator if the occasionally quoting inside your text file is annoing you. It has to quote all strings that contain `','` right now:

```
with open('data.csv', 'w', newline="") as new_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter='|')
    csv_writer.writerow(headings)
    csv_writer.writerows([t_data])
```

To get:

> Number of confirmed cases in New Zealand|Number of probable cases|Number of confirmed and probable cases|Number of cases currently in hospital|Number of recovered cases|Number of deaths
>   1,112|-1|339|1|1,451|0|8|-3|1,065|29|16|2

Comment: I want to display this data on my webpage what is the best way of doing this.

Comment: @robin Your question was about getting the data into a csv. How to get the csv into your page is a different question. No idea how your homepage is build - you need to place the data into a page that your serve as your homepage so it depends on what you use: Django, Grok, WebPy, Pyramid, and Flask or some other. Try it out, if it does not work, ask a new question.

Answer (score -1):

When dealing with the data generated, you need to remove the `,` out of string to be converted to integers before adding it.. something like:

```
value = td.text.strip().replace(',', '')
t_data.append(int(value))
```

From that, things get a bit straightforward, your new t_data will look like:

```
[1112, -1, 339, 1, 1451, 0, 8, -3, 1065, 29, 16, 2]
```

I guess you can now figure out the writing easily. Another thing is the csv file, there's no header to it.. maybe would be interesting to write also the headers onto it.

Comment: writing csv handles inplace `,` by quoting the value - thats all built-in to the csv writer and reader methods. no need to convert anything.

Comment: Ok. So, you show the code, you show what you get, you show the original table format... but at the end, your question is not that clear of what's the desired output format/goal. Maybe try to read [ask] in order to rephrase your question in a way that the community would be able to help... something like:

"I would like my csv to have each line containing the following format:  NAME, TOTAL_VALUE, CHANGE" (and showing the error/trials code)

Comment: i mixed up who asked with who edited the question.. sorry!